# Should I use id numbers or meaningful texts in HTTP requests payload

Tags: api, rest

I have been searching about that and I couldn't find any references to endorse my impression that it's worthier to use meaningful texts inside requests body or response than just ids in situations where you have a restricted and small scope of possible values. Let me exemplify that. What should I use:

```
{
 "idSystemStatus": 1
}
```

or that:

```
{
 "systemStatus": "alert"
}
```

What is the best practice? Could you please give me references?

Answer (score 0):

Being an API, means that other systems will read it. So it is important to be bandwidth-optimized, and it makes sense to use shorter and numeric values where appropriate.

But if you explicitly need wording, try to make that as short and concise as possible.

Comment: Do you have any references for that? I understand your concern but I'm yet not sure what is the best practice. Also, I could change my example to use a uid and so, it would be as long as a word.

Comment: No ref, I speak from experience. Also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187323/rest-api-status-as-integer-or-as-string which has few good pointers.